# Track asynchronous Azure operations using the fluent API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-management-api, azure-fluent-api

I know you can track normal operations using the standard API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations

However I was wondering if there was a known way to utilize the [Fluent Azure Management Libraries](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) to track long async operations such as VM operations etc. For example the VM restart method is a void Task which does not return an operation-id for tracking.

```
async Task IVirtualMachineScaleSetVM.RestartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  await this.RestartAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it seems that it's hard to trace VM restart status which does not return an operationId.

Logging in the fluent Azure management libraries for .NET leverages the underlying [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/AutoRest) service client tracing.

Create a class that implements `Microsoft.Rest.IServiceClientTracingInterceptor`. This class will be responsible for intercepting log messages and passing them to whatever logging mechanism you're using.

```
class ConsoleTracer : IServiceClientTracingInterceptor
{
    public void ReceiveResponse(string invocationId, HttpResponseMessage response) { }
}
```

Before creating the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure` object, initialize the `IServiceClientTracingInterceptor` you created above by calling `ServiceClientTracing.AddTracingInterceptor()` and set `ServiceClientTracing.IsEnabled` to **true**. When you create the Azure object, include the `.WithDelegatingHandler()` and `.WithLogLevel()` methods to wire up the client to AutoRest's service client tracing.

```
ServiceClientTracing.AddTracingInterceptor(new ConsoleTracer());
ServiceClientTracing.IsEnabled = true;

var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithDelegatingHandler(new HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler())
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

For more details,  you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/dotnet-sdk-azure-concepts.md).